# How to call class method from NSString in obj-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring, meta

In obj-c, how can I call

`[myClass myString];`

where `myString = @"myMethod";`

Which should be the equivalent of `[myClass myMethod];`

Not sure if this kind of meta language manipulation is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[myClass class]` returns the metaclass, class methods are called on the metaclass. E.g.

```
[NSString someClassMethod];

NSString *instanceOfString = @"some string instance";
[[instanceOfString class] someClassMethod];
```

EDIT: I misread the question. Use `NSSelectorFromString` to get a SEL from an NSString. That's documented in Apple's [Foundation Functions Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html) where you'll also see `NSClassFromString`, `NSStringFromClass`, `NSStringFromSelector`, `NSStringFromProtocol` and `NSProtocolFromString` amongst others.

Comment: That's the metaclass. My question is on the method call part, i.e. I know the class, but I only have a string for what method to call.

Comment: Oh, misunderstood. NSSelectorFromString is the way to go. I'll edit, though I'll just end up with much the same answer as Tom Jefferys and JeremyP.

Comment: Points given for the hustle. :)

Answer (score 10):

```
[myClass performSelector: NSSelectorFromString(myString)];
```

Docs:

- [-performSelector:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000052-BBCBGHFG) sends the selector specified to the receiver
- [NSSelectorFromString()](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-BCIEICGB) converts an `NSString` into a selector (type `SEL`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSSelectorFromString`, something along the lines of the following should work:

```
 SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"myMethod");
 [myClass performSelector:selector withObject:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SEL mySelector = NSSelectorFromString(@"myMethod");
[myClass performSelector:mySelector];
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, in case you need more flexibility in argument and/or return types than `performSelector:` and friends will give you, have a look at the [NSInvocation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class.